# React hooks: API failure results in component re rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

when my API returns error my page parent component rerenders and I lost all my data of child components. Strange is the case as when I try again to submit, similar error is thrown by API **but** my parent component doesn't re-render thus filled data remain preserve which I want for the first time error as well.

configured hooks in parent component called on first time api errors which results in broken behaviour while 2nd time as component doesn't rerender hooks doesn't call as well.

Tried to make code as minimum as possible.
**Parent** has **ChildA** and **ChildA** has **ChildB** as child component.
I filled some details in ChildB and then submit the form with button available in Parent. Form submission calls an API which results into error due to validation failure on backend. But this error re-renders Parent which causes all details filled in ChildB to be lost. when I again fill same details and submit the form...though same API error is thrown(as Expected) but this time Parent doesn't re-render and ChildB information remain preserve.

Any idea why Parent rerenders with first time API error

```
const Parent = ({ match, history, location }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
      let filterValuesUsedInChildBComponenet = someAPICall()
  }, [dispatch, param]);

  const saveHandler = (isExit) => {
      dispatch(
        campaignFormOperations.saveForm(
          record,
          null,
          null,
          isExit
        )
      );
  };

  return (
    <ChildA
      filterValuesUsedInChildComponenet={filterValuesUsedInChildComponenet}
      updateFilterValuesUsedInChildComponenet={updateFilterValuesUsedInChildComponenet}
      ..
    />
  );
};


const ChildA = (props) => {

  ...
  return (
    <ChildB
      filterValuesUsedInChildComponenet={filterValuesUsedInChildComponenet}
      updateFilterValuesUsedInChildComponenet={updateFilterValuesUsedInChildComponenet}
      ..
    />
  );
};
```

Any suggestion are welcome.

Comment: We dont see your code 

Comment: @Rashomon added details